# Foundation framework | Sticky Div?

Tags: frameworks, zurb-foundation, sticky

Is it possible, using [Foundation Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/), to make a scrollable sticky div [like this (StyckyScroll)](https://github.com/rickharris/StickyScroll)?

For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="eight columns">
    Very long content here
  </div>
  <div class="four columns">
    Small but SCROLLABLE CONTENT here
  </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is that the sticky div gets out of the parent container.**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foundation supports a couple types of sticky navigation. If you're looking for a navbar-type implementation, check out the docs on their top bar module (docs and example at: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html)

You can implement a sticky navbar in foundation by wrapping the normal top bar module like so:

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        YOUR NAVBAR MARKUP HERE
    </nav>
</div>
```

If you're looking for sticky navigation that's less omnipresent than the top-bar, you can also use their Magellan plugin (docs and example at: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html)